# Control parallelism with conditional locking?

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, recursion, locking

[image]

To summarize, I have a recursive task and I want to use all 4 of my processors to process this really big tree faster. My current production implementation uses `Parallel.ForEach` and is out of control, pegging all 4 of my cpus and running out of memory quickly. So, I know the right algorithm can give me all 4 cpus at 70-80%, which I have found will get the crawling job done quickly whilst leaving the UI responsive and my computer overall responsive for light UI user-driven tasks. This task is a background task.

The method I am attempting (listed below) is parallel and recursive, and I want to use conditional locks to limit the threads.

I want this code to use a max of 4 threads to keep recursively creating 20 scary heads until a nesting depth of 10 is reached in all branches. I changed it from 2 to 20 heads because that's more like my actual problem. My actual tree is only 4-5 levels deep but quite wide, and each node requires alot more cpu than `Console.WriteLine`.

This has not as easy to accomplish as I envisioned it would be.

I'm trying to make all threads greater than 4 wait until enough of the threads that came before finish to bring the total threads back down to 4 before they continue. So it's ok if a few more than 4 threads get created, as long as the ones > #4 are just waiting. Hence the conditional waiting (locking) part.

My code example is just for concept purposes obviously and is just what I tried. Feel free to diverge from my implementation details.

Edit: I changed my implementation last night to use SemaphoreSlim, a cousin of fat boy slim, to handle the traffic cop role. It only results in 2 processors busy at 20%.

My next iteration will probably involve looping four times to create 4 workers that crawl nodes independently of one another. But the difficulty with that is, they'll need to know which nodes (subtree) are currently being crawled or have already been crawled by another worker. I'm not sure if that's less complicated than the approach below. It does seem the listed approach avoids processing nodes in the wrong order (e.g. child before parent), but maybe that's just an illusion given off by the appearance of the structure of the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public class ScaryTeddy
    {
        public ScaryTeddy(ScaryTeddy parent, int position)
        {
            Parent = parent;
            Position = position;
            DoSomethingHeavy();
        }

        public BlockingCollection<ScaryTeddy> Heads = new BlockingCollection<ScaryTeddy>();
        public ScaryTeddy Parent { get; set; }
        private string _path;
        public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                if (_path == null)
                {
                    if (Parent != null)
                        _path = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Parent.Path, Position);
                    else
                        _path = Position.ToString();
                }
                return _path;
            }
        }

        public int Position { get; set; }

        // short in duration but taxing on cpu and memory
        private static void DoSomethingHeavy()
        {
            // look at all the text inside every jpg in my pictures. Admire my girl friend's beauty!
            FileSystem.FindInFilesFileList(@"C:\Documents\Pictures", new List<string>() { "Exif" }, new List<string>() { "*.jpg" }, null, null);
        }

        // these have to be static b/c CreateScaryTeddy is static
        private static readonly SemaphoreSlim SemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(4, 4); // 4 cpus
        private static object _lock = new object(); // one object for all instances? Is that correct?
        private static int _scaryTeddyFactories = 0; // just a way to inspect how many are concurrent

        // this only produces 2 cpus working at about 20%; I want all 4 working at 70-80%
        public static ScaryTeddy CreateScaryTeddy(ScaryTeddy parent = null, int position = 1)
        {
            SemaphoreSlim.Wait();
            lock (_lock) _scaryTeddyFactories++;
            var scaryTeddy = new ScaryTeddy(parent, position);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} with slot {1} created Scary Teddy {2}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, _scaryTeddyFactories, scaryTeddy.Path);
            lock (_lock) _scaryTeddyFactories--;
            SemaphoreSlim.Release();

            if (scaryTeddy.Path.Split(".".ToCharArray()).Length <= 10)
            {
                Parallel.For(0, 20,
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 },
                    babyHead => scaryTeddy.Heads.Add(CreateScaryTeddy(scaryTeddy, babyHead)));
            }

            return scaryTeddy;
        }
    }
```

**Edit: The results**

[image]

All 4 processors almost pegged out - perfect!

Console output shows a thread pool is involved. I guess the way semaphore works is the open slot is ALWAYS #4?

```
Thread 1 with slot 1 created Scary Teddy 1
Thread 6 with slot 2 created Scary Teddy 1.10
Thread 1 with slot 3 created Scary Teddy 1.0
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1668) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3bd0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread 5 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.10.0
Thread 1 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.0.10
Thread 6 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.10.10
Thread 3 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.0.0
Thread 5 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.10.0.0
Thread 1 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.0.10.0
Thread 9 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.0.10.10
Thread 6 with slot 4 created Scary Teddy 1.10.10.0
```

[image]

We have 4 threads doing work, which is what I wanted, and the rest of the pool is waiting, which IMHO is not too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `outOfControl` throttling mechanism with a `new SemaphoreSlim(4)`. This is built-in to the framework. (Also, you are reading `_scaryTeddyFactoryCount` without locking which is unsafe. But that goes away when you use the semaphore.)

Make the static variables instance variables. At the moment their values are dangerously shared between all instances.

You might want to switch to an asynchronous style of waiting (e.g. using `async/await` or `ContinueWith`) to use less threads. Your recursion tree is quite big and you might end up with very many threads waiting for the semaphore. You might even exhaust the thread-pool and deadlock.

You are adding items to a collection (`scaryTeddy.Heads.Add`) in an unsynchronized way. That's unsafe.

Comment: +1 for the code review. I have tag .net 4.0. Can I use async / await? I'd like to, do you know how I can? Thanks!

Comment: oh forgot to mention, I found `SemaphoreSlim(4,4)` last night and modified my code last night to include it, and it still didn't result in 4 processors being used at 70% to get the job done as fast as possible whilst leaving my UI responsive. I'll post my revised code for you here in a few.

Comment: What do you mean by 70%? Your box has 4 cores and you want to use all 4, but only at 70%?! It would be better to use a lowe thread priority and not throttle to 70%.; Anyway, the semaphore must be held while all the work is being done. In your code there is almost no work being done. I assume you have not included the actual processing. If the ctor of ScaryTeddy is supposed to perform the work, this should do it.; Regarding async in .NET 4, I don't know. Search for what options you have there. I think there are some.

Comment: Throttling work on a single CPU is actually pretty hard. You'd need to insert sleeps... Don't do that. Ideally, you have one (runnable) thread per CPU core. Anyway, is there still a problem is you insert (simulated) CPU work into the teddy ctor? I can't see why this shouldn't work. In case of a big tree you will of course experience OOM because the number of nodes is about width^height.

Comment: ok I'll change the constructor to do some heavy math or something very cpu (and I suppose memory) intensive, for a better test. I won't sleep. And I'll test the result. I don't want to run OOM before the whole tree is finished. Thanks.

Comment: Ok it's "good enough"! You did it! If you see anything wrong with my final listing let me know -- this is going into "production" (it's my utility to help me at work). Thanks again!

Comment: Trying to install Async CTP 3.0 to enable async / await in VS 2010 caused me to lose my 2012 and damaged my 2010 so that it won't start :(

Comment: You can try setting the semaphore limit to `Environment.ProcessorCount + 1` in case some threads are doing IO. That way there's a spare thread that can utilize the CPU while another is doing IO.